# How can I get rid of the leading dash in this html code?

Tags: html, css

Within a table cell, I'm trying to display an image, and to its right centered vertically against the image two lines of text.  The following does the centering, but the anchor tag from the first line wraps to the beginning of the next line.  I've noticed this in both Chrome and IExplorer.

How do I clean up the display so that it doesn't display the leading dash on the second line?

```
<td>
  <div>
    <a href="some_other_page.html" title="Something Else">
      <img class="tblimg" src="my_picture.png" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle"/>
    </a>
    <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
      <a href="javascript:do_stuff(''); calc_stuff()">This thing</a>
      <br>This has a leading line from the above anchor
    </span>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That leading dash is actually the underline that is shown on links by default. To remove that, just apply the style: `text-decoration: none;` to your `<a>` tags.

Below is the results when I remove the default link styling:

```css
#image-link { 
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div>
    <a href="some_other_page.html" title="Something Else" id="image-link">
      <img class="tblimg" src="my_picture.png" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle"/>
    </a>
    <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
      <a href="javascript:do_stuff(''); calc_stuff()">This thing</a>
        <br/>This has a leading line from the above anchor
    </span>
  </div>
</td>
```

**EDIT: If you want to remove the underline for just the image, give the `<a>` tag that wraps around the image an ID or unique class (in my sample, I gave it an ID of `image-link`) and declare `text-decoration: none;` for that ID/class.**

Comment: Okay. thanks. So you're telling me it makes sense to you that it wraps to the next line?  That is, is there a way to leave the underline but not have it wrap?

Comment: It's not exactly wrapping to the next line. Regardless, I edited my answer above to include what you wanted. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try `box-decoration-break:none;` and `text-decoration:none;` as well as `border:none;`

Answer (score 0):

Add an inline:block style to the anchor containing the image, like so:

```
<a href="some_other_page.html" title="Something Else" style="display:inline-block">
```